# Show that $\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)=\operatorname{span}(v_1,2v_1+v_2)$ (proof structure)

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Show that $\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)=\operatorname{span}(v_1,2v_1+v_2)$.

It's pretty obvious, but I want to show how exactly I show it?

I want to show that $\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)\subseteq \operatorname{span}(v_1,2v_1+v_2)$ and $\operatorname{span}(v_1,2v_1+v_2)\subseteq \operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)$

---

Firstly showing $\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)\subseteq \operatorname{span}(v_1,2v_1+v_2)$

$v_1=(1)(v_1)+(0)v_2$

$2v_1+v_2=(2)(v_1)+(1)(v_2)$

---

Now showing  $\operatorname{span}(v_1,2v_1+v_2)\subseteq \operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)$

$v_1=(1)(v_1)+0(2v_1+v_2)$

$v_2=(-2)(v_1)+(1)(2v_1+v_2)$

---

Therefore the spans are equal. Is this the right way to prove this?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: Yes, you expressed both vectors as linear combinations of each other respectively, showing that each is a subset of the other and therefore are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your argument shows that $sp(v_1, 2v_1+v_2)\subseteq sp(v_1,v_2)$, and

the second part shows that $sp(v_1,v_2)\subseteq sp(v_1, 2v_1+v_2)$.